# Targeting C++/WinRT with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, cmake, c++-winrt

I'm working on compiling a CMake-based third party C++ shared library for use within a UWP application.

Per documentation on MSDN, I've been building with the flags `-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0`. While this is very useful for flagging any disallowed or unavailable APIs, my understanding is it sets the `/ZW` flag, which enables `C++/CX`.

This is mostly fine except for some minor points (for example: the library deals with networking, and makes use of the variable name `interface` which is apparently a reserved keyword by C++/CX).

More fundamentally, since I'm building a standard C++ library, I'd rather use standard C++ (C++/WinRT). Is there a way to tell CMake to target the WindowsStore SDK but without carrying along C++/CX?

Comment: My reading of the [corresponding code](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/cmVisualStudio10TargetGenerator.cxx#L2736-2740) says it turns _off_ the `CompileAsWinRt` flag, which would add `/ZW-`

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I've misidentified the root cause of my problem.

The base of it is -- when I build, the variable name `interface` is getting picked out as a keyword, which tells me the C++/CX compiler is being used, not standard C++. I'll dig through the cmake source code some more and reword my question as needed. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: An MCVE and corresponding error code would help us help you.

Comment: Sure -- sorry, I thought this was a more general issue. I'll re-word the title/body to target my specific issue with the interface keyword, including a minimal example.

Comment: Turns out I'm indeed conflating issues here. It appears `interface` is a reserved keyword on MSVC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/interface?view=vs-2019) regardless of whether WinRT/UWP is in the picture. Apologies for the noise, and thanks for the pointer to the cmake code @Botje

Answer (score 1):

This is a fallacious question. Underlying problem has nothing to do with C++/CX or UWP -- Including `windows.h` pulls in `combaseapi.h` which has `#define interface __STRUCT__`. And so, MSVC treats interface as the `struct` keyword.

[The original, incorrect answer cited `interface` being a reserved keyword on MSVC per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/interface?view=vs-2019. This is also not correct, as pointed out in the comments]

Comment: MSVC is a C++ compiler. It doesn't introduce non-standard keywords. The documentation you linked to describes the keyword `__interface`. The leading double underscore moves it into the namespace reserved for use by the implementation. That namespace can be used by any compiler for any purpose.

Comment: Aha -- thanks. Yes, it turns out my problem is that combaseapi.h (inside windows.h) has `#define interface __STRUCT__`